# How to disable all bottons on page with javascript if all of them contains specific name like "Not Available"?

Tags: javascript, button, auto, disabled-input

I have a page contains many buttons
I want to disable all buttons that has name "Not Available" all at once automatically by javascript code
Basically I want the code to read the page and disable all buttons with that name
even if a button name is "Sorry, Not Available" javascript will target it because it got "Not Available" in it.
if buttons doesnt have that name they stay active and not disabled.

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  if (button.innerText.match(/Not\sAvailable/gi)) {
    button.setAttribute('disabled', 'true')
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed Ali its working
problem is its working in another page but I have a page that shows buttons in table using php code and that javascript code did not work with it!
Is there any other way? maybe a php code instead?

Comment: If the php code is in a seperate file than your javascript. Connect them together with script that refers to your javascript code that should fix?

Comment: I fixed that problem! its all working now I just inculded the code into the php.
My problem now is: I want to make that javascript code changes the class of the button too from class="mybutton" to class="mybutton2"
I think it's only one more code in the same code to make it change the class
How to do that?

Comment: Can you tell me?

Comment: Just add `button.classList.replace("myButton", "myButton2")` before the `if statement`

Comment: I added it after the if statement to not affect other buttons. Thank you